# Shortcut to change typeface?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typefaces, shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to change the typeface?

I press control-T which brings up the character selector which is nice. Then I press tab and it hides all the menus instead of going to the next field in the character selector :(

[image: Adobe Illustrator Typeface Selector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method to circumvent at least **one** click in many panels. The UI simply is not constructed to remove all "click events", other than via scripting/actions.

You **must** click at least one field in *many* panels before tab/shift-tab will navigate between fields.

There are also no shortcuts which I am aware of which can be used to focus on a field inside a panel. Shortcuts will merely open/close panels.

Comment: Thank you so much! That sucks but that makes sense to me.

Comment: It seems like some panels do automatically have the input field selected however.
https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/601447-illustrator-bugs/suggestions/38988784-illustrator-v24-0-on-macos-10-15-1-rotate-panel-h

Comment: Well sort of. Some **commands** have shortcuts.. like Rotate (command-r) and those **commands** may *also* be possible on a panel. It's the command that has a shortcut, not the panel.

Comment: Although the panel when opened immediately focuses to the first input field which is super cool. I wish all panels did that.